# Deleting Facebook apprequest,how can I achieve it?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am in the process of developing a JavaScript app that sends notification to users.Im using the method below for this

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
       message: 'The message description',
       to: '123456',
       title: 'The message title',
       data : ''
      },function(response){
     console.log(response);
});
```

Now I have got  few questions,it says on Facebook guide that its the developer's job to delete the app request.How do I delete the app request ? I know its possible using the code below,how do I get the requestId though? Do I have to get it from the URL?

```
FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

My second question: Am I able to pass certain params so that I can load the page based on the notification type.I'm planning to give the user to send different types of notifications to their friends .If its a gift notification I want the user to be send to the gifts page of the app or if its a message i want the user to be send to the  messages page of the app.I wan this to happen either when they click on the notification or the ACCEPT button from the APP CENTER.

If its a duplicate my apologies,any advice much appreciated.thanks